# MySql Connection lost Delphi

Tags: mysql, multithreading, delphi

I am writing DB app (with MyDac Component and MySql server) and i need your help. Imagine a Situation:
1. Application starts - connection exists, everything is OK.
2. Then the MySql server crashes or just connection problem occurs
3. User is trying to Select some data from DB
BOOM! Application is goin to infinite loop (is trying to establish the connection)

I don't know what to do. I thing that it would be nice to put the query in a thread. I already know that i have to create a separate connection for this Thread. Due to lack of experience on working with threads i can't do this.  It would be great if you write an example or give me an advices. I hope for your help,thank you

Comment: What sort of connection handling do you have?

Comment: `"I already know that i have to create a separate connection for this Thread. Due to lack of experience on working with threads i can't do this."` To create a separate connection for the thread means you have to create a connection from code and use that connection solely in that thread. I do wonder though, how the application gets in a loop. I would think that that only happens when you catch any exceptions and just try again until you get a proper result, which (obviously) might never happen. But to help you further, any exception message and a piece of code might help.

Comment: Actualy, if there is no connection and you are trying to perform some operations, you send a request and wait for response. But it wont come, because the server is shutted down. I use MyDac (TMyConnection component with direct connection to DB). The property "Local Failover" is "true" and on "OnConnectionLost" event  retrymode:=rmReconnectExecute. Application continue to work if connection is established, but it would stay at loop all this time;

Comment: fix your back-end. servers that go down shouldn't be tolerated.

Comment: Please describe the scenario where you keep losing your connection to the DB server. Besides that, any such loop as you're doing should implement a limited number of attempts before failing and alerting the user or at least doing something different.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid infinite attempts of reconnecting to the server, you can use a counter variable. For example, you can use the following code:

```
var
  RetryCount: Integer;

procedure TMainForm.MyConnection1ConnectionLost(Sender: TObject;
  Component: TComponent; ConnLostCause: TConnLostCause;
  var RetryMode: TRetryMode);
begin
  if RetryCount < 2 then begin
    Inc(RetryCount);
    RetryMode := rmReconnectExecute;
  end
  else begin
    RetryCount := 0;
    RetryMode := rmRaise;
  end;
end;
```

In this case, MyDAC will try to reconnect to the server twice, and in case of failure will generate an exception.